# Getting NoClassDefFound while running jar in docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, netsuite

I have added 3 external jars which is not present on the maven repository. I mentioned external jars as a system scope in pom.xml file -

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.suitetalk</groupId>
        <artifactId>suitetalk-axis-proxy-v2022_1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
        <systemPath>${pom.basedir}/libs/suitetalk-axis-proxy-v2022_1-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

In STS/Eclipse, the project is not giving errors and all functionality is working well as expected. But if we build project by - `mvn clean package` then also it is not throwing any error. When I run docker image by docker run command then getting error as -
[image]

Summary - External Jar's classes are not found while running the docker image. getting error as NoClassDefFOund error.
Can someone please help me to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance for your efforts!

**Regards,**
Prashant VIDHATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because java runtime is looking for them inside the docker container. To make it work, you need to add the libraries to docker image (`ADD` command in Dockerfile) or add the volume to map your local filesystem folder into the container filesystem folder.

You can also install the dependencies into your local maven repository, and then they will be included in the "fat jar" after build.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=${pom.basedir}/libs/suitetalk-axis-proxy-v2022_1-1.0.0.jar -DgroupId=org.suitetalk -DartifactId=suitetalk-axis-proxy-v2022_1 -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: Thanks, @dey. It worked for me. Its my bad, I was executing the above command locally and then building jar on AWS env. now I executed on the same place. it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the instruction for the spring-boot-maven-plugin to copy the system scope into the spring-boot jar.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also `pom.` in `${pom.basedir}` is redundant:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/suitetalk-axis-proxy-v2022_1-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, @John. After adding IncludeSystemScope it worked for me.